# SQL MAX Date in Subquery Where Clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I would like to have the results with the MAX DATE from SUBQUERY.

Does max(Date) in where clause works this way?

I tried this one:

```
select A.ARTIKEL,
       A.BEZEICH,
       (select B.BS from B
        where B.ARTIKEL = A.ARTIKEL and B.BS = 'EA'
          and max(B.BUDATUM)) as BOOKINGS
from A
where A.ARTIKEL = '1236589'
```

Comment: *"Does max(Date) in where clause works this way?"* No, you cannot using aggregate functions in the `WHERE`. It also doesn't make sense that you have only one side of the boolean expression; `WHERE  max(B.BUDATUM)` *what*?

Comment: Start with doing a LEFT JOIN instead. Then use a window function to get the B row you want.

Comment: I went with the left join, and afterwards I used the windows, because it went further with the statement.

Answer (score 0):

You cant use max date like that in a where clause but you can order the result by date and fetch the top record.

```
SELECT A.ARTIKEL,
       A.BEZEICH,
       (SELECT top(1) B.BS from B
        WHERE B.ARTIKEL = A.ARTIKEL and B.BS = 'EA'
        ORDER BY B.BUDATUM DESC) as BOOKINGS
FROM A
WHERE A.ARTIKEL = '1236589'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use an aggregation like that but an outer apply would be a solution:

```
select A.ARTIKEL,
       A.BEZEICH,
       x.BOOKINGS
from A
outer apply (select top(1) B.BS from B
        where B.ARTIKEL = A.ARTIKEL and B.BS = 'EA'
        order by B.BUDATUM desc) x(Bookings)
where A.ARTIKEL = '1236589'
```